# Add data to tf.data.Dataset API in batches

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a dataset that I'd like to pass to `tf.data.Dataset` API for dispatching. However, I need to read in a large number of data files and preprocess them before passing over to `tf.data.Dataset`. I do not want to read all the data in to memory at once. Currently, I've been reading one file at a time, batching them, then read next file. i.e

```py
import itertools

class DataBatcher:
    def __init__(self, list_of_files):
        self.list_of_files = list_of_files
        self.init_index = 0
        self.x, self.y =  self.loop_files()

    def loop_files(self):
        for one_part in itertools.cycle(self.list_of_files):
             # read in one_part file, which has N examples
             # doing some prepocessing
             # self.x and self.y will be of shape [N, feature_num], [N,] respectively
             yield self.x, self.y

    def gen_batch(self, batch_size):
        # discard remaining data if it't not enough for a batch
        if (self.init_index + batch_size) > self.y.shape[0]:
            self.x, self.y =  self.loop_files()
            self.init_index = 0
        x_batch, y_batch = self.x[self.init_index: self.init_index + batch_size, :], self.y[self.init_index: self.init_index + batch_size]
        self.init_index += batch_size
        return x_batch, y_batch 

data_batcher = DataBatcher(files)
x_sample, y_sample = data_batcher.gen_batch(10)
```

`x_sample` and `y_sample` are then passed to the tensorflow model through `feed_dict`. But I want to change to `tf.data.Dataset` to improve the performance. I found `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` to read in the entire dataset before dispatching and `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` to read in one example at time, both of which are not using resources efficiently, is there any way in between? something like using generator to yield part of the dataset?

Comment: `from_generator` can wrap arbitrary Python code. This means that yes, you can totally yield parts of the dataset at once. But it's up to you to make sure that at the end, whatever comes out of the dataset into your model has a "sensible" structure.

Comment: yes I tried to have the generator yield part of the data, but during batching, that part is treated as one data example, not multiple examples

Answer (score 0):

Your batching logic is not needed if using the dataset API. Probably best to:

1. Use `Dataset.from_generator` on you existing generator function
2. then use the `dataset.batch()` method to batch to whichever size batch you need.

Perhaps something like this:

```
data_batcher = DataBatcher(files)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_batcher.loop_files, output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32))
batched_data = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

Comment: The problem with passing `data_batcher.loop_files` to `from_generator` is that it will treat each output of `loop_files` as one example, which in fact, it's N examples from one file. My code example was not clear about this, I'll add comment to it.

Comment: yes, I can do that. I just assumed that could be even less efficient than just use `feed_dict` with my own batching. although I have not tested it. :/

Comment: I've inadvertently deleted that comment! sorry, combination of indecision and misclicking! :-) Think you have gotten gist of what I was trying to say anyway!